# Struts 2 radio button value.?

Tags: java, struts2

i have following code in jsp used with struts2 radio button i want to know which radio button is selected in my action class so can anyone give me solution on this.

code:

```
<div>
   <s:radio cssClass="formFieldRadio" name="selectAction" list="{'Postponed To'}"/>
   <s:radio cssClass="formFieldRadio" name="selectAction" list="{'Suspended'}"/>
   <s:radio cssClass="formFieldRadio" name="selectAction" list="{'cancelled'}"/>
</div>
```

i use diffrent radio with same name so that are displayed each in new row...

Answer (score 0):

I dint understand why you need all the radio buttons with the same name.. If the names are different add the getter/setter for all the radio buttons in the actions with there same names, the in action exectute() method check the values of the radio button for true or false as

```
if(formFieldRadio == true)
```

u get to know its checked or not

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you should do it like this:

```
<s:radio name="selectAction" list="#{1:'Postponed To', 2: 'Suspended', 3: 'cancelled'}" />
```

Then in your action you should expect a numeric value (in this case, 1, 2 or 3) in an selectAction variable.

make sure you have the `theme="simple"` attribute so you can play freely with your css.